# How to put all element from a dictionary in a database

Tags: python, database, list, dictionary

I show you my problem:

To begin,
I have a dictionary of list in python like this :

```
"links": [{"url": "http://catherineingram.com/biography.html", "type": {"key": "/type/link"}, "title": "Biography"}, {"url": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4lJK9cfXP3c", "type": {"key": "/type/link"}, "title": "Interview on Consciousness TV"}, {"url": "http://www.huffingtonpost.com/catherine-ingram/", "type": {"key": "/type/link"}, "title": "Blog on Huffington Post"}]
```

My goal is to got only url and title of link  and put them in a database.
For the moment I worked only with url and I did it :

```
for record in csv.DictReader(open(INPUT_FILE, 'r'), fieldnames=COLUMNS, delimiter='\t'):
    j = json.loads(record['json'])
 result=[]

    if 'links' in j:
        for link in j['links']:
            result.append({'url': link['url']})
            a=(link['url'])

            print(a)
            links=a


    else:
         links = ''
```

The result is :

```
http://catherineingram.com/biography.html
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4lJK9cfXP3c
http://www.huffingtonpost.com/catherine-ingram/
```

So it's perfect, I got exactely what I wanted but the problem now is when I put links in my database with:

```
links=a
```

I got only the last element of url in my database and not the 3 url
So I try to have 3 url in my database but I got only last.
I hope you can help me on my problem

Thanks to listen me !!!!

ps:

If you want more detail on code it's here :

```
for record in csv.DictReader(open(INPUT_FILE, 'r'), fieldnames=COLUMNS, delimiter='\t'):
    j = json.loads(record['json'])
result=[]

    if 'links' in j:
        for link in j['links']:
            result.append({'url': link['url']})
            a=(link['url'])

            print(a)
            links=a


    else:
         links = ''

         #   print(n)
            #links_url.append(n['url'])
            #links_title.append(n['title'])
            # links_url.append(n['url'])
            # links_title.append(n['title'])



    c.execute('INSERT INTO AUTHORS VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',
          [record['key'],
           j.get('name'),
           j.get('eastern_order'),
           j.get('personal_name'),
           j.get('enumeration'),
           j.get('title'),
           bio,
           alternate_names,
           uris,
           j.get('location'),
           j.get('birth_date'),
           j.get('death_date'),
           j.get('date'),
           j.get('wikipedia'),
           links
          ])
db.commit()
```

Comment: First, you need to show us how your indentation is *exactly*. As it is currently displayed, the code cannot compile. After that is corrected, I *suspect* your `c.execute` statement needs to be indented because right now it is not at the same level as `a=(link['url'])` and it probably should be. By the way. the parenthesis in `a=(link['url'])` accomplishes nothing nor does any harm.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to answer me !

My goal is to put all my url in my database

So I did it :

```
for record in csv.DictReader(open(INPUT_FILE, 'r'), fieldnames=COLUMNS, delimiter='\t'):
    j = json.loads(record['json'])
    if 'bio' in j and 'value' in j['bio']:
        bio = j['bio']['value']
    else:
        bio = None
    if 'alternate_names' in j:
        for n in j['alternate_names']:
            alternate_names = n
    else:
        alternate_names = None
    if 'uris' in j:
        for n in j['uris']:
            uris = n
    else:
        uris = None




    if 'links' in j:
        for link in j['links']:
            dico=({'url': link['url']})
            print(dico['url'])
            links=dico['url']




    else:
         links = ''

         #   print(n)
            #links_url.append(n['url'])
            #links_title.append(n['title'])
            # links_url.append(n['url'])
            # links_title.append(n['title'])



    c.execute('INSERT INTO AUTHORS VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',
          [record['key'],
           j.get('name'),
           j.get('eastern_order'),
           j.get('personal_name'),
           j.get('enumeration'),
           j.get('title'),
           bio,
           alternate_names,
           uris,
           j.get('location'),
           j.get('birth_date'),
           j.get('death_date'),
           j.get('date'),
           j.get('wikipedia'),
           links
          ])
db.commit()
```

But when I did it, all other elements ( bio,alternate names ...) work but not links beause I need to do an other method because it's a list of dictionary like it :

```
"links": [{"url": "http://catherineingram.com/biography.html", "type": {"key": "/type/link"}, "title": "Biography"}, {"url": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4lJK9cfXP3c", "type": {"key": "/type/link"}, "title": "Interview on Consciousness TV"}, {"url": "http://www.huffingtonpost.com/catherine-ingram/"
```

For moment I take only element url in a dictionary and I try to put in my database all the url of links. It works perfectely when I have only 1 url  but sometimes I have 2 or 3 Url and when it happens, only the last url is in my database and not others.  Thtat's my problem

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment to your question you have some indentation issues. I am only taking a guess as to what you are trying to achieve. You also have assignment to variables that are then never referenced in the code shown, so it may very well be that they have not been declared at the right level.

```
for record in csv.DictReader(open(INPUT_FILE, 'r'), fieldnames=COLUMNS, delimiter='\t'):
    j = json.loads(record['json'])
    result=[] # what do you do with variable result? Shiuld this be delclared before the 'for record' statment?
    if 'links' in j:
        for link in j['links']:
            result.append({'url': link['url']})
            a=link['url'] # what do you do with variable a?
            print(a)
            links=a # do you need both variables a and links?
            c.execute('INSERT INTO AUTHORS VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',
                [record['key'],
                 j.get('name'),
                 j.get('eastern_order'),
                 j.get('personal_name'),
                 j.get('enumeration'),
                 j.get('title'),
                 bio,
                 alternate_names,
                 uris,
                 j.get('location'),
                 j.get('birth_date'),
                 j.get('death_date'),
                 j.get('date'),
                 j.get('wikipedia'),
                 links
                ])
    else:
         links = ''
         #   print(n)
            #links_url.append(n['url'])
            #links_title.append(n['title'])
            # links_url.append(n['url'])
            # links_title.append(n['title'])

db.commit() # should this be moved to following the c.execute statement rather than doing one commit for all the inserts?
```

The above is now writing multiple rows with identical data bit with different links. That leads to an unnormalized database. Could you have meant instead to have written out one row where the column contained 3 links? That, too, would be a case of an unnormalized database. Again, I am just guessing as to what you meant by "I try to have 3 url in my database but I got only last."